QGIS : Open raster .gdb Esri format
I try to open an Esri raster.gdb in QGIS (Open 25m Raster DEM, Altalis, Calgary, canada).
I use 3.36.1-Maidenhead QGIS (Version de GDAL/OGR 3.8.4)
Some "layers" are created but I can't do anything with them.
It seems to be attribute tables with only one record.
And I have the feeling that all the rasters are not imported.
In the original .gdb directory, there are 117 files, the biggest one (raster ?) weighs 4GB.
To import the .gdb directory, I use the classical method (Add vector layer, directory, gdb database) you can find everywhere on YouYube.
Do I do something wrong?


I use the classical method (Add vector layer, directory, gdb database)

That's the classic way to add vector data. If you want to add raster data, normally you could use the Add raster layer method, but this doesn't work for FGDB rasters. Instead, either drag FGDB rasters into your map from the Browser pane or use the Layer menu -> Data Source Manager -> Browser tab:

If that doesn't work, re-check your GDAL version in QGIS, just in case the GDAL version QGIS is using is different to the GDAL/OGR 3.8.4 you note in your question as raster support was only added to the GDAL OpenFileGDB driver in GDAL version 3.7.
To check:

In QGIS, click Help -> About




So for the above QGIS example, only the 2nd QGIS install would be able to read FGDB raster data.

Thanks a lot. You drove me to a solution ! :-)
I stopped using "add vector layer" (wrong way, even if it's a database) and I used "add raster layer". Then, I let QGIS dealing with a zipped file (the .GDB file was zipped). And it works. But if the .GDB file wasn't zipped, It would have been a problem. I didn't manage to find the appropriate command to add a .GDB raster ... Best Francis
